# making a pause button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button, pause

I've been making ping pong game watching tutorial and in the end decided to enhance a bit by adding paused button, I added and everything worked just fine but when I restart the game it was still being paused. Then I decided that I needed to add a paused check variable `paused = false;` and for some reason the state is the same, please help me!

```js
const resetBtn = document.querySelector('#resetBtn');
const pauseBtn = document.querySelector('#pauseBtn');    

paused = false;
running = true;
pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', pauseGame);
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', resetGame);

gameStart();
function gameStart(){
  createBall();
  nextTick();
};
function nextTick(){
    if(running && !paused){
        intervalID = setTimeout(() => {
            // some code
            nextTick();
        }, 10)
    }
    else{
        displayPause();
    }
};
function resetGame(){
    // some code

    paused = false;

    // some code
    updateScore();
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    gameStart();
};
function pauseGame(){
    running = !running;
    paused = true;
    if(running){
        nextTick();
    }
};
```

```html
<button class="buttons" id="pauseBtn">pause</button>
<button class="buttons" id="resetBtn">reset</button>
```

[image: Here u can see paused game]

[image: after I pressed reset button]

I'm expecting to resume game when user press restart button.

Comment: Shouldn't you also call `nextTick` when you 'reset' the game? And do something about `running` now being `false`?

Comment: What is `running` (where is it declared)? What is `// some code`? What does `gameStart()` do?

Comment: Why do you need both `running` and `paused` flags?

Comment: While it still works, better use `clearTimeout` instead of `clearInterval` to clear timers created with `setTimeout`

Comment: "*Im expection so that unpauses game when u press restart button*" - where is that button in your code? Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve], we can't help you otherwise.

Comment: Since you handle the pause in your nextTick function, I think your pause/unpause functions just need to set the state of your paused variable. You don't need to manually called nextTick from the pause function since it's running on an interval anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need both a `running` and `paused` variable. They are essentially the same thing.  Just use `running` since you've already got that working.

Since you are using `setTimeout` to run your game, you need to use `clearTimeout` when to clear it, not `clearInterval`.  If you were using `setTinterval` that's when you'd want to use `clearInterval` to clear it.

In the below code I've changed your timeout amount to `100` just so it's easier to see what's happening in the console, it goes by too quickly at `10`. You should probably keep it at `10` for your game though

```js
const resetBtn = document.querySelector('#resetBtn');
const pauseBtn = document.querySelector('#pauseBtn');    

running = true;
pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', pauseGame);
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', resetGame);

gameStart();
function gameStart(){
  //createBall();
  nextTick();
};
function nextTick(){
    if(running){
        intervalID = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('game running', intervalID);
            nextTick();
        }, 100)
    }
    else{
        //displayPause();
        console.log('paused!')
    }
};
function resetGame(){
    // some code

    running = true;

    // some code
    //updateScore();
    clearTimeout(intervalID);
    console.log('reset!')
    gameStart();
};
function pauseGame(){
    running = !running;
    if(running){
        console.log('unpaused!')
        nextTick();
    }
};
```

```html
<button class="buttons" id="pauseBtn">pause</button>
<button class="buttons" id="resetBtn">reset</button>
```

Comment: thanks lol, we posted same solution at once, but thank u

Answer (score 0):

the issue is resoled, i actually didn't need another variable like paused,
all i needed was to add running to true like below, thanks for your attention

```js
function resetGame(){
running = true;
```

};